# How to check if a point is behind a plane (along a vector)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, 3d

I have an arbitrary vertex $v$ from a plane with a normal vector $\vec{n}$, I have a ray vector $\vec{r}$ I am shooting through the plane sort of, from a point $p$, I want to know if the point is behind the plane relative to the ray vector instead (I tried applying the same logic [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330210/585488) asper the point being behind the plane relative to the normal vector, but that didn’t work)

> **Example** 
>  plane $(0,0,0)$ $(4,0,0)$ $(0,0,4)$ $(4,0,4)$ 
>  normal $\vec{n}$ $[0,1,0]$ 
>  ray $\vec{r}$ $[1,1,0]$ 
>  point $p$ $(1,2,2)$ 
>  I meant I tried picking an arbitrary vertex $v=(4,0,4)$ and doing $\vec{r} \cdot (p-v)$ and it turned out incorrect. Although for $v=(0,0,4)$ it works as expected.

Please how can one decipher if a point is behind a plane relative to some vector?

here’s my plane with the normal and ray vectors
[image]

here’s how one would normally check if a point is behind a plane (i.e. $\vec{n} \cdot (p-v)$):
[image]
[image]

here’s what I want to do instead:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I apologize for not being able to convey the idea understandably, I would be supporting this question with a diagram later today when I am chanced. The problem is given a plane and a point, determining which side of the plane the point is while moving along the ray so to say. Normally checking if a point is on either sides of a plane would be checking that the point is behind or infront of it along the normal to the plane

Comment: I believe I've understood it now (see my answer). If you meant something different, just say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define
$$s:=\left(\vec n\cdot\vec r\right)\left((p-v)\cdot\vec n\right).$$

**Case 1:** $s=0$
Then, the ray vector $\vec r$ is parallel to the plane or your point $p$ is in your plane.

**Case 2:** $s>0$
Then, your point $p$ is in the same half space which the ray vector $\vec r$ points into.

**Case 3:** $s<0$
Your point $p$ is behind the plane w.r.t. the ray vector $\vec r$.

This method works since $\vec n\cdot \vec r$ checks if $\vec n$ and $\vec r$ "are on the same side" of your plane, while $\left((p-v)\cdot\vec n\right)$ checks if $p$ is on the same side as the normal vector.